# Expression result unused on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-warnings

ALL,

Following gives the warning:

```
std::list<MyList>::iterator it = std::next( m_lines.begin(), m_currentLine - 1 );
for( it; it != m_lines.end(); ++it )
```

The red squiggly indicates an error on the `it;`.

What is the problem here and how do I fix it?

I'm on OSX 10.13 with Xcode 9 if it matters.

TIA!

Comment: Your for loop doesn't need the first it. It does nothing. You already defined it.

Comment: The expression it in the first part of the for loop serves no purpose at all.

Comment: You have already done the initialization part of the for loop here - ```std::list<MyList>::iterator it = std::next( m_lines.begin(), m_currentLine - 1 );```, So, you can simply write the for loop as ```for( ; it  != m_lines.end()  ; ++it)```.

Comment: @dukeforever, thank you. You gave an explanation and the code, so I up-voted your answer.